# How to start a PostgreSQL with timeout set in Gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, timeout

I test concurency behaviors and I want to validate code when computation is long. I need to configure PostgreSQL timeout.

Locally, in my docker-compose I have the following configuration :

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.8
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all", "-c", "log_destination=stderr", "-c", "lock_timeout=3s" ]
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

The following test passes :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PostgreSQLConfigurationTest.GenericConfiguration.class)
public class PostgreSQLConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    void shouldLockTimeoutSetTo3s() {
        String sql = "SHOW lock_timeout";
        String lockTimeout = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, String.class);

        assertEquals("3s", lockTimeout, "lock_timeout attendu valant " + lockTimeout);
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    public static class GenericConfiguration {
    }
}
```

In the CI configuration file, I don't know how to the same :

```
check:
  services:
    - name: postgres:14.3
      alias: postgresql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `service.entryoint` or `service.command` keyword (see [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#services)). Actually, you should be pretty much be able to copy your information from the compose file.